# FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory') full_key: detector

Tags: python, path

Error executing job with overrides: []
Error in call to target 'inference.detector_yolov5':
FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')
full_key: detector

I didn't find any errors in the configuration file, and I didn't know what to do

Resolve this file path issue

Comment: Are you sure the file exists and that the path to the file is correct? It would help to have a more information on what code you are trying to run and what your file directory looks like.

Comment: I have solved the problem. The file is corrupted. Anyway, thank you for your answer

Comment: Ah that wasn't what I would have expected. Then the error message is confusing, good to know that it can be caused by a corrupted file. Thanks for the update.